# Related lists in VtigerCRM 6.4

Tags: vtigercrm

I am trying to create a sql query in mysql which shows all  Documents linked to a project task. I cannot find the table which shows the related columns to link both tables.
The documents are inthe table  Vtiger_notes and project tasks are in the table Vtiger_ProjectTask. Can anybody know how these are related in mysql?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of relations beetwen modules in vTiger are managed by a third table. In this case the third table to join is the ** vtiger_senotesrel**
Supposed that your project task id is 12345 the query to execute is

```
SELECT vtiger_notes.* FROM vtiger_notes inner join vtiger_senotesrel on vtiger_senotesrel.notesid= vtiger_notes.notesid inner join vtiger_crmentity on vtiger_crmentity.crmid= vtiger_notes.notesid  inner join vtiger_crmentity crm_pTask on crm_pTask.crmid=vtiger_senotesrel.crmid where vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0 and crm_pTask.crmid=12345
```